# Renaming [piwik] to [matomo]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The Open Source project [piwik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/piwik) has recently been renamed to "Matomo".

https://matomo.org/blog/2018/01/piwik-is-now-matomo/

As everything apart from the name stays the same, it would be great if this tag could be renamed to [matomo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matomo) and a synonym could be created.

Comment: Someone might want to look at updating the tag wiki accordingly

Comment: Done: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18910635